# Animation nodes, finding current material for object

Tags: animation-nodes

I need to to make an object list and a material list from 100 existing objects. Making the object list is simple, I just box-select the objects and in animation node I use the "From Selection" option from the "create Object List" node.

Unfortunately, there is no such option for materials list. Is there I way I can automate creating a materials list from an object list? I have tried the "expression" node, but was not able to extract the materials list, due to my limited knowledge of python.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Sincerely,

Patrice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to StackExchange. You can easily get the material of the object with Expression Node by using `Obj.material_slots[Index].material`. Here I have made **AN-Material of Object** group-node which allows getting material of any object:
[image]

For Object List, you can use **Loop Node** and **AN-Material of Object** to the materials of objects in the object-list:
[image]

Blend File:

[image]

Comment: It works and it does exactly what I needed it to do. Thank you so much for your precious help.